# " list of files and subfoldes owner information" with powershell script

Tags: powershell, windows-7, server

I can see some in this link"https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1722-get-fileowner"

I tried but the examples but neither of them was working for me.

Comment: And the question is...? Please outline the approach you already tried and where you got stuck, preferably with code examples.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it

```
get-childitem c:\users\usera\documents -Recurse | foreach{
    $f = $_.FullName
    $o = Get-Acl $f | Select -ExpandProperty Owner
    Write-Output "$f is owned by $o"
}
```

Comment: Thanku!!! It's working

Comment: Is there a way where i can also get the details of users along with the owner of files and subfolders?

Comment: what details do you want to find about user ?

Comment: The names of the user/groups who have access to the file/folder.

Comment: You mean the display name like firstname, lastname or something? Because the above does tell you the username.

Comment: I need a csv file with user information just to make sure that every subfolder and file in the parent directory has a user/group.